# Define global from within a function

Tags: scope, macros, scheme, racket

I need some function which among other stuff would define a new global symbol. So that I could use it like this:

```
(define (func-prototype symbol value comment)
  (define symbol value) ; this should somehow be reformulated
  (format "~a=~a   !~a\n" symbol value comment))

(define string-list (map func-prototype
                         '((s1 1 "first value")
                           (s2 20 "second value")
                           (s3 300 "third value))))
```

and be able to get the following results:

```
> string-list
'("s1=1  !first value\n"
  "s2=20  !second value\n"
  "s3=300  !third value\n")
> s1
1
> s2
20
> s3
300
```

Can this be implemented as a function or it is possible to do that only with the help of macros? Could you please suggest any possible implementations or at least give some hints/references that might be helpful?

Comment: Strong recommendation toward Oscar's answer.  Defining global variables dynamically is usually a very bad idea due to potential name clash and difficulty in controlling the scope.  Confining the bindings  to a hash table, instead, is usually a simpler and more effective approach.

Comment: If you give us more background on the motivation, that may prompt better answers.  Why are you trying to do this?  For documentation purposes on functions?  For defining functions that have optional keyword arguments with default values?

Comment: The motivation is following: There is a modelling software which has its own 'language', but that language is ugly (IMHO). I am trying to write a wraparound which would wride the code instead of me. The formatted strings in my post show how a definition of a variable looks like in the target language. For some variables it is enough to create just such a string. For others I also need to use their values inside the wraparound. I guess that Oscar's solution would be the best for my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rethink the general approach, making it simpler. My suggestion: define a global hash table and inside the function add bindings to it, for example:

```
(define value-map (make-hash))

(define (func-prototype symbol value comment)
  (hash-set! value-map symbol value)
  (format "~a=~a   !~a\n" symbol value comment))
```

Use it like this:

```
(define string-list
  (map (lambda (lst)
         (apply func-prototype lst))
       '((s1 1   "first  value")
         (s2 20  "second value")
         (s3 300 "third  value"))))

string-list
=> '("s1=1   !first  value\n"
     "s2=20   !second value\n"
     "s3=300   !third  value\n")
```

And wherever you need to refer to one of the symbols in the hash table, do this:

```
(define (get key)
  (hash-ref value-map key))

(get 's1)
=> 1
(get 's2)
=> 20
(get 's3)
=> 300
```

Answer (score 2):

In general it is not possible to accomplish what you are trying to accomplish in the way you described.  Your only hope would be to write stuff out to a file and then `load` that file into an interactive session.  But even then.

In scheme you can't introduce top-level names, such as your desired `s1`, `s2`, and `s3`, except at the top-level.  To do so, you could define a macro as:

```
>(define-syntax define-foo
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ name value)
     (define name value))))

>(define-foo s1 1)
<undefined>
> s1
1
```

If you try to use that macro in a function, it is no dice because the body of a function *must* end with an expression and any definition forms, like what the above macro would expand into, become local variables.  That is:

```
(define (func-prototype name value comment)
   (define-foo name value)
   name)

>(func-prototype 's1 1 "com")
1
> s1
<error>
```

One approach that you could take that would work if your string-list is a constant would be as such:

```
> (define-syntax declare-variables
    (syntax-rules ()
      ((_ (name value comment) ...)
       (begin
         (define name value)
         ...))))

> (declare-variables (s1 1 "com") (s2 20 "com") (s3 300 "com"))
> s1
1
```

This gets it done (I've ignored using 'comment') but, as I said, requires a compile time string-list.

One possibility you might think would work, but wouldn't, would be to use `eval` as:

```
   (eval '(define s1 1) (environment ...))
```

but 'eval' only works for expressions, not declarations.  Which gets me back to 'load' as a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

First, consider whether you really want to do this, or whether a different solution (like a hash table) would work as well.

You can do this with [reflection and dynamic evaluation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/reflection.html) using the `eval` procedure.

```
;; define-variable-with-value! : symbol any -> void
(define (define-variable-with-value! name value)
  (eval `(define ,name (quote ,value))))
```

The `quote` is important; otherwise you risk reinterpreting a *value* as an *expression* to evaluate. To see the difference, consider the example

```
(define-variable-with-value! 'x (list 'error "kaboom"))
```

Comment: Note of course that not all Scheme's support single-argument `eval`; In other Schemes you might have to pass an explicit environment to `eval`, e.g. the `(interaction-environment)`.  (And also, even R5RS-compliant Schemes are not required to support `define` expressions, as implied by GoZoner's answer.)  So really, check your implementation's docs.

Comment: EVAL does not portably accept non-expressions: "Evaluates expression in the specified environment and returns its value. Expression must be a valid Scheme expression represented as data, and environment-specifier must be a value returned by one of the three procedures described below. Implementations may extend eval to allow non-expression programs (definitions) as the first argument"  Thus '(define ...) can't be expected to work as the first argument to eval.

Comment: Of course, the question was tagged Racket, so its not like we need to get on Ryan's case about his answer.  :)

Comment: Yes sorry; perhaps I'll untag 'Scheme'